# Quota exceeded trying to create file with HTML File API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, fileapi

In a packaged Chrome app, I'm trying to read from a file in the PERSISTENT storage, and create it if it doesn't exist:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile('file.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                console.log(this.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
         }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
});
```

But I'm getting `The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota.` error.
TEMPORARY storage is giving me the same error.
Is there anything I should specify in the manifest.json?

Comment: You should _request_ the required quota first: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-requesting-quota

Comment: @CBroe I get `0` when I print out `grantedBytes`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding `unlimitedStorage` to the manifest.json permissions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running a cordova app on a browser platform.
I fixed the issue by removing useless (and old) files stored in filesytem directory.
You can find this directory there (on windows8):

```
%userDirectory\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue when my hybrid cordova application running on ripple -Chrome>settings>history>advance>checked all unnecessary files and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Or invoke chrome with `--unlimited-storage` parameter:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unlimited-storage`