# FileSystemWritableFileStream.write causes quota error

Tags: javascript, file-system-access-api

I'm using File System Access API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) to read and write a file into disk. This is my code;

```
const writable = await cacheFileHandle.createWritable({ keepExistingData: false });
await writable.write(JSON.stringify(cache));
await writable.close();
```

This code fails with `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota.` error. This began when the file reached 10MB. Is there any way to solve this?

Note: 
I already tried the HTML File API solutions.

- I tried `window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(window.PERSISTENT, 10240*10240,()=>{...},()=>{...})`. That didn't work.
- Another solution was to put `unlimitedStorage` to the manifest.json, but this is a react app, so that didn't help either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455634/quota-exceeded-trying-to-create-file-with-html-file-api

Comment: @ElvisPimentel, already tried that (pointed it out in the "note:"). Sadly that is for chrome extensions and packaged apps. This is completely different, as this doesn't have a manifest or anything.

Comment: I think your problem is elsewhere, since [`WritableStreamDefaultWriter.write()`](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#default-writer-write) doesn't fail with a `DOMException`, but with a `TypeError`. You probably hit a storage quota issue somewhere else.